# Sitecore Rich Text Html Editor Profile - set global default

Tags: editor, wysiwyg, sitecore, richtext

OK I can't believe this can't be found anywhere so I'm asking the question.

Is there a way to set the default Html Editor Profile in Sitecore so I don't have the override the Source field on each individual Rich Text field?

e.g. I want to make this the default option for the Html editor:

```
/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Medium
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Its an old question but here is the solution I found in Sitecore 6.5 - I was looking to do the same thing in 6.5:

You can change the value to the path of your default editor in the web.config. This will change is across all fields where the source is not defined.

```xml
<!--  HTML EDITOR DEFAULT PROFILE
      Path to the default html editor profile.
      Default value: /sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Default
-->
<setting name="HtmlEditor.DefaultProfile" value="/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Default"/>
```

Comment: For some reason this is not working for me in Sitecore 7.2. I have changed the value to Rich Text Full, but it is not updating

Answer (score 14):

It seems to fall back to the "/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Default" in case the source is not defined. Thus, if you try to modify this default profile, every RTE field will obtain these modifications by default, without specifying the source.

Never tried it myself, though...

Comment: Correct - it's worth duplicating the Rich Text Default before you start modifying it, just in case you need to refer back to it.

Comment: Yes and that is how I had done it .. I'm assuming that is the only way then, and that there is not option to switch? .. just to change that particular node around to suit?