# Change default RTE in Sitecore 6?

Tags: editor, sitecore, sitecore6, rich-text-editor

The default RTE in Sitecore 6.2 is the Default profile, which have very limited options. I want to change the default RTE to the Medium profile - but how do i do this, without going through all my templates and chaning the source to the medium RTE?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490004/sitecore-rich-text-html-editor-profile-set-global-default/2490292#2490292 ?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple actually. Just switch over to the core database, locate the profiles (it's under System / Settings / HTML Editor Profiles) and rename the 'medium' profile to 'Rich Text Default' (don't forget to change the old default to something else too)