# Customizing the Sitecore Rich Text Editor's default configuration

Tags: telerik, sitecore, sitecore6

Using Sitecore 6.4, and I would like to customize the available buttons (eg Bold, Spell Check) given by the Rich Text Editor.

For clarification, I am referring to the popup editor displayed when you choose "Show Editor" from a particular Field's menu. I do not want to customize the editor on a per Item basis, rather globaly.

At first I had thought modifying the standard telerik config file (\sitecore\shell
\Controls\Rich Text Editor\ToolsFile.xml) would work, however it does not seem to affect a change.

[Another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490004/sitecore-rich-text-html-editor-profile-set-global-default) mentioned opening the Content Editor and modifying the Html Editor Profiles node, however that does not exist in version 6.4.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Yan Sklyarenko is right you're probably in the wrong database. If you've logged in under desktop mode you can see a database image on the bottom right and if you click on it you can change your context database to "Core". Alternately you can append the querystring key value pair "sc_content=core" to your url if you're in the content editor.

Once the Core database page is loaded you can open the content editor and browse to "/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles". There is a Rich Text Default folder which holds all the buttons that will be displayed when no source is set on your Rich Text field. Editing this list will affect your wysiwyg buttons on Rich Text fields that do not have a source field set to anything.

There are also a few other profile types and you can also create a custom profile folder with a mix of buttons. To get your wysiwyg to display these profiles you would need to set the source folder on your Rich Text fields at a template level (this would be back in the master database). I've written more a detailed explanation of this method [here](https://markstiles.net/blog/2011/3/15/rich-text-editor-profiles/).

Answer (score 4):

You're probably looking in wrong database. Switch to core and you'll find the path mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490004/sitecore-rich-text-html-editor-profile-set-global-default).