# Sitecore how to hide/disable HTML tab from your Rich Text Editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Could someone suggest how to hide/disable HTML tab from your Rich Text Editor on sitecore?

I had a look at [this](http://sitecoreaustralia.wordpress.com/2010/06/16/top-100-cool-things-in-sitecore-completed-list/), but requires a change on Sitecore core rich text XML.

Problem with this solution is we need to modify the XML for each instance and what about upgrades?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the Core database (you can switch using the icon in the bottom right next to the clock) you can go to `/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/*profile you want*/buttons/HTML view` and deny read-access on that for your users. Alternatively, at least in Sitecore 6.5, there's a profile without the HTML view. It's called Rich Text IDE. You can set the datasource field of a Rich Text field to that one, and not have the HTML view.

That's only removing the HTML option on the bottom left though, I'm not sure how to remove the Edit HTML option you have before you've opened the RTE itself (where you have Show Editor/ Suggest Fix / Edit Html). Looking at [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876360/customizing-the-sitecore-rich-text-editors-default-configuration) it might be you'll have to change the XML anyway.

The way we've got upgrades and different instances handled is by having the changed file in source control, and making sure we include it when building a deployment package.

Answer (score 2):

Adding onto Trayek's great answer - you can remove access to the "Edit HTML" as  outlined by Alex Shyba below:

1. Go to the core database, locate the field definition item: 
   /sitecore/system/Field types/Simple Types/Rich Text/Menu/Edit Html
2. On the Security Tab, click “Assign” and select the role you don’t want this option to be available to. Deny inheritance of this item or specify other security settings that make sense for your needs.

I added "Everyone" and then selected the "X" by Inheritance for Items, and the "Edit HTML" option was removed.

Taken from:
http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2009/10/quick-tip-remove-edit-html-option-for.html